# sudo make not working on os x... "make not found"

Tags: macos, mac, make, build

I recently got a new MacBook Air and decided to do a fresh install without using the migration assistant.

I'm running into issues building software that requires "Make". I do have xcode installed, but for some reason it seems like "make" isnt installed. Here is an output.

```
petros$ sudo make
Password:
sudo: make: command not found

petros$ gcc -v
-bash: gcc: command not found
```

Any clues?

Comment: Did you install Xcode after doing your fresh installation? What is `echo $PATH`? Which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: I did install Xcode after the fresh installation. I am using XCode - 4.0.2, here is my $PATH.... petros$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `/Developer/usr/bin` to your [path](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/how-do-i-set-path-and-other-environment-variables/284351#284351) and try again.

Comment: Sorry for the even noobier question, but how do I do that?

Comment: @Peter Follow the instructions in the linked answer, under the OS X section.

Comment: I've read through the post, but I still don't get exactly what I should be doing. Can you show me an example?

Comment: @Peter `sudo bash -c "echo /Developer/usr/bin > /etc/paths.d/developer_tools"`. Close the shell and reopen, then try again.

Comment: Didnt work... I guess Im gonna have to reinstall

Comment: @Peter What happens when you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you installed Xcode and the other development tools as part of this fresh install? For example, are you sure you're not running Xcode from a different hard drive partition or something?

You should probably run the Mac OS X installer again and make sure to customize the install and select all the Xcode & developer tools.

Comment: I downloaded Xcode on its own from the dev site, used unix tools, and Im running it on the my root drive. Id rather not resort to reinstalling if possible... but thanks for the tip. Ill use that as a last resort.

Comment: @Peter Then just re-install Xcode. It won't delete any files you've added, but if you've modified any of the files that come with the Xcode developer tools, those modified files will probably get overwritten by clean copies.